# Cannot implement array initialization in TreeNode Template C++ Scapegoat Tree

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I get an initialization error for a TreeNode class constructor… This is the function:
TreeNode* a  = new TreeNodens; Is the issue here, not sure what I have to add to TreeNode but it needs some type of tweak!

```
template <typename T>
void ScapegoatST<T>::rebuild(TreeNode<T>* node){
    int ns = getHeight(node);
    TreeNode<T>* p = node->getParent();
    TreeNode<T>* a  = new TreeNode<T>[ns]();
    TreeNode<T>* r;
    
    packintoArray(node,a,0);
    if (p == NULL){
        r = buildBalanced(a,0,ns);
        r->setParent(NULL);
    } else if (p->getRight() == node){
        TreeNode<T>* Tr = buildBalanced(a, 0, ns);
        p->setRight(Tr);
        p->getRight()->setParent(p);
    } else {
        p->setLeft(buildBalanced(a,0,ns));
        p->getLeft()->setParent(p);
    }
    
}
```

Here is the TreeNode.h:

```
#ifndef TREE_NODE_H
#define TREE_NODE_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class TreeNode{
public:
    TreeNode(T nData);
    virtual ~TreeNode();
    
    T getData();
    TreeNode<T>* getLeft();
    TreeNode<T>* getRight();
    TreeNode<T>* getParent();
    
    void setData(T nData);
    void setLeft(TreeNode<T>* nleft){left=nleft;};
    void setRight(TreeNode<T>* nright){right=nright;};
    void setParent(TreeNode<T>* nparent){parent=nparent;};
    
    template <typename S>
    friend class ScapegoatST;
    
private:
    T data;
    TreeNode<T>* left;
    TreeNode<T>* right;
    TreeNode<T>* parent;
};

template <typename T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode(T nData){
    data = nData;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
TreeNode<T>::~TreeNode(){
    delete left;
    delete right;
    delete parent;
    data = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
T TreeNode<T>::getData(){
    return data;
}

template <typename T>
void TreeNode<T>::setData(T nData){
    data = nData;
}

#endif
```

I tired creating a constructor for the array initialization but it wasn’t successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you've created the constructor `TreeNode(T nData)`, which prevents the constructor with no arguments `TreeNode()` from being generated, but you call that constructor when you do `new TreeNode<T>[ns]()`.

One solution would be to add a constructor `TreeNode()`, with a body like so:

```
template<typename T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode() {
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}
```

This will mean that constructing a `TreeNode` with no `nData` will result in the node's `data` field being default-initialized (for primitive types, it will contain an undefined value, and for classes it will act like `T()` was called to construct the `data` value).